# How to get the details of applications deployed on Tomcat server?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, server-monitoring, tomcat-manager

I am trying to develop a web application to monitor a Tomcat server using Spring Boot. I need to retrieve information on all server instances and applications deployed on the Tomcat server.

I have been searching for resources on how to use the Tomcat Manager API for this, but have not been able to find clear documentation or examples. Could someone please guide me to the right resources or suggest alternative solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated."

Comment: Have you considered using existing projects that do this kind of thing, or is the goal to develop it yourself? Is it important to use certain APIs (there isn't really a "Tomcat Manager API"), or are you just trying to get some information regardless of technique? Finally, are you expecting this "application" to run inside of the Tomcat container, or separately from it e.g. on another host/server?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands

Comment: thank you for your valuable response. I want to develop myself without using any existing projects. its not mandatory to use certain APIs. I am just trying to retrieve performance metrics and log monitoring using any other technologies. and my web application is expected to run on another server. I want to monitor multiple servers.  what about using jmx ?